# Somar valores de um array PHP

Tags: php

Estou precisando somar os valores vindos do banco de dados. Para isso, estou usando o código abaixo:

```
while($jmCarrinho = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlCarrinho)){
    .....
    $totalLargura = $jmProdutos->Largura * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    $totalAltura = $jmProdutos->Altura * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    $totalComprimento = $jmProdutos->Comprimento * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    $totalPeso = $jmProdutos->PesoProduto * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    .....
}
```

Com esse código, ele me traz o seguinte resultado:

```
Produto 1 | Total multiplicando a qtd da compra com as dimensões do produto

Unitário: 13 | Total Largura: 13
Unitário: 11 | Total Altura: 11
Unitário: 25 | Total Comprimento: 25
Unitário: 1 | Total Peso: 1

Produto 2 | Total multiplicando a qtd da compra com as dimensões do produto

Unitário: 21 | Total Largura: 42
Unitário: 13 | Total Altura: 26
Unitário: 35 | Total Comprimento: 70
Unitário: 1 | Total Peso: 2
```

O que eu preciso é somar o valor total de cada dimensão. Ex.:

```
Total de Largura: 55
Total de Altura: 37
Total de Comprimento: 95
Total de Peso: 3
```

Tentei com os seguintes códigos abaixo, mas não consegui (coloquei apenas de um como exemplo):

```
$somar = array();
while($jmCarrinho = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlCarrinho)){
....
   $totalLargura = $jmProdutos->Largura * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
   $totalAltura = $jmProdutos->Altura * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
   $totalComprimento = $jmProdutos->Comprimento * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
   $totalPeso = $jmProdutos->PesoProduto * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;

    $somar["TotalPeso"] = $totalPeso;
}

// Tentativa 1
echo "Peso " .array_sum(array_column($somar, "TotalPeso"));

// Tentativa 2
echo "Peso " .array_sum($somar["TotalPeso"]);

// Tentativa 3
$soma = 0;
foreach($somar as $key => $value){
    $soma += $value["TotalPeso"];
}
echo $soma;
```

O resultados são 0 ou nulos.

Comment: Só uma observação, se você multiplicar a quantidade do produto por cada uma das 3 dimensões dele, você estará calculando o espaço necessário para a quantidade de `qtd³`, ou seja, para `2` produtos, espaço para `2³=8` deles. Se quiser apenas 2 mesmo, multiplique apenas por 2 em uma das dimensões e as outras ficam inalteradas.

Comment: Olá Dudaskant. Desculpe, não consegui entender muito bem. Na verdade esses cálculos do post seria para o frete do Correios no caso de haver mais de um produto e/ou quantidade no carrinho. Seria para aplicar em cima desse raciocínio?

Comment: Sim, por exemplo, pegue 2 caixas de leite. Quando você coloca uma em cima da outra, só a altura total muda, que é multiplicado por 2, porém largura e comprimento permanecem com os mesmos valores, entendeu?

Comment: Entendi. Realmente estou quebrando a cabeça aqui com esse frete com mais de um produto/quantidade. Sua dica foi muito importante. Irei partir dessa premissa. Obrigado.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por quê você já não soma os valores dentro do próprio laço `while`?

```
$somaLargura = 0;     // Será a soma das larguras
$somaAltura = 0;      // Será a soma das alturas
$somaComprimento = 0; // Será a soma dos comprimentos
$somaPeso = 0;        // Será a soma dos pesos

while($jmCarrinho = mysqli_fetch_object($sqlCarrinho)){

    $totalLargura = $jmProdutos->Largura * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    $totalAltura = $jmProdutos->Altura * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    $totalComprimento = $jmProdutos->Comprimento * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;
    $totalPeso = $jmProdutos->PesoProduto * $jmSomarQ->QtdProdutos;

    ...

    $somaLargura += $totalLargura;
    $somaAltura += $totalAltura;
    $somaComprimento += $totalComprimento;
    $somaPeso += $totalPeso;
}

echo "Você precisará de uma largura total de {$somaLargura}";
echo "e de uma altura total de {$somaAltura}";
echo "e de um comprimento total de {$somaComprimento}";
echo "e de um peso total de {$somaPeso}";
```

Comment: Perfeito Anderson. Funcionou! Obrigado.